# Is it possible to only mount specific volumes using --volumes-from?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-volume

I ma currently working on a CI/CD pipeline on Gitlab and I am using a **containerised Gitlab runner** (Docker-in-Docker situation)
I am trying to create a test job for the application I am developing (a miniature Fast API web app that scrapes some images over the network based on GET requests)

The app is also containerised.

I need to build the **app** image, run the **app**, send some requests to it, let it store the scraped images and then check for the saved images in the location the **app** aved them.

Sounded easy until I found out that I can't mount the directories in **the Gitlab runner**, since I am using a mounted `/var/run/docker.sock` in **the Gitlab runner** so that the docker can only mount directories from the host machine (which **the Gitlab runner** has access to)

So I did a lot of reading and found out some information and so far I can see a solution by identifying the container I am running in (**the Gitlab runner** one) and mounting its volumes into the **app container** using `--volumes-from`. The issue is, that it (to my knowledge) mounts all the volumes, but I need only to mount one... the one I added to **the Gitlab runner** `config.toml` file as the working volume. Also I need to be able to write into that one volume but leave the other ones intact (probably for safety reasons... i am not sure but i don't think I should give access to the /cache volume or /certs volume of a gitlab runner or smth)

Is there a way to only mount a certain volumes from a running container so that I can access the files from both the **runner** and **app** container?

Am I able to specify a named volume for **the Gitlab runner** in the `config.toml` file so that I can access the files generated by the **app** throughtout the job or the whole pipeline?

**OR**, if i am doing something very stupid, is there a more elegant way of testing my **app**'s side-effects and functionality using the Gitlab CI/CD pipelines?

Comment: I have found out several issues that request similar functionalities. If I camoe across them again and remember, I will add them there as an answer. In other words, the functionality is not there.